# Autowired Bean not of correct type when building with Codehaus & EnversHibernateToolTask

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, dependency-injection

This issue only crops up when I build with my QA Profile e.g. mvn clean install -Pqa

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'reportingService' must be of type [com.testProjects.project.backoffice.service.BackofficeReportingService], but was actually of type [$Proxy78]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    ... 54 more
Tests run: 563, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 562, Time elapsed: 19.656 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

Relevant bits of my POM:

```
<profile>
    <id>qa</id>
    <properties>
        <tomcat.url>http://etc:8081/manager/text</tomcat.url>
        <war.name>project-backoffice</war.name>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <deployer>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <properties>
                                    <context>${war.name}</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </deployer>
                    <wait>true</wait>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                        <type>remote</type>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <type>runtime</type>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>${tomcat.url}</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                            <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                            <cargo.remote.password>admin</cargo.remote.password>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>redeploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

And the build portion:

```
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin </artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                    <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.EnversHibernateToolTask" classpath="${compile_classpath}" />
                    <hibernatetool destdir="${project.build.directory}">
                        <annotationconfiguration configurationfile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/backoffice.hibernate.cfg.xml" propertyfile="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/hibernatetools.properties" />
                        <hbm2ddl create="true" drop="true" export="false" format="true" outputfilename="project-schema.ddl" />
                    </hibernatetool>
                    <hibernatetool destdir="${project.build.directory}">
                        <annotationconfiguration configurationfile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/backoffice.hibernate.docs.cfg.xml" propertyfile="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/hibernatetools.properties" />
                        <hbm2ddl create="true" drop="true" export="false" format="true" outputfilename="document-schema.ddl" />
                    </hibernatetool>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
```

The controller in question:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reporting/")
public class ReportingController {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportingController.class);

    @Resource
    private BackofficeReportingService reportingService;
```

The service in question:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
@Service
public class BackofficeReportingService {
```

Tried adding in a definition to the context, also tried setting the CGLIB proxy, to no effect.

```
<bean id="reportingService" class="com.project.backoffice.service.BackofficeReportingService"/>
```

Any help would be really appreciated, it's making my build "unstable" and I'd love to know what's going on.

Comment: Is `BackofficeReportingService` implementing any interface? If not, create one and reference this class only by that interface. Adding CGLIB to your CLASSPATH and enabling CGLIB proxies *should* help as well.

Comment: It's not, but I'll try that and report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to Tomasz Nurkiewicz for this.
Creating an interface for the reportingService fixed this.

I'm not clear as to why this issue started and why the unchanged in months reportingService, or why most of the other services are injected fine without an interface, but I am very grateful Tomasz! Huzzah for a green sphere instead of a yellow one!